# Handling nulls in powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I'm sure this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything on here or on the Internet. I'm trying to use powershell to query an oracle database which it seems to do ok until it hits a null value and then it blows up.

Here is my code.

```
# Create a datareader for a SQL statement 
$sql="select * from legacydb.ebt_invoice_dtl where premnum = 397743"
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand( $sql,$conn)
$reader=$command.ExecuteReader()

# Write out the result set structure 
for ($i=0;$i -lt $reader.FieldCount;$i++) {
Write-Host  $reader.GetName($i) $reader.GetDataTypeName($i) 
}

# Write out the results 
while ($reader.read()) {
$dtl_id=$reader.GetDecimal(0)  
$invoice_id=$reader.GetDecimal(1)
$debtor=$reader.GetInt64(2)
$premise=$reader.GetInt64(3)
$license=$reader.GetString(4)
$invoice_num=$reader.GetInt64(5)
$deb_cred=$reader.GetString(6)
$inv_ref=$reader.GetString(7)
$rate=$reader.GetDecimal(8)
$charge=$reader.GetDouble(9)
$usage=$reader.GetInt64(10)
$tax=$reader.GetDouble(11)
$rate_code=$reader.GetString(12)
$inv_date=$reader.GetDateTime(13)
$missed=$reader.GetString(14)
$change_date=$reader.GetDateTime(15)
$dnp=$reader.GetString(16)

Write-Host "$dtl_id $invoice_id $debtor $premise $license $invoice_num $deb_cred        $inv_ref $rate $charge $usage $tax $rate_code $inv_date $missed $change_date $dnp "
}
```

Error Message:

> Exception calling "GetString" with "1" argument(s): "Column contains
>   NULL data" At C:\users\klynch\test.ps1:34 char:27
>   +     $dnp=$reader.GetString <<<< (16)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: "then it blows up" - Could you let us have the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the "SELECT *" and explicitly name your fields. Then you could use NVL/COALESCE to convert your NULL values into something you could handle. It's more typing up front, but it documents what you're selecting and might help you avoid errors later if the table structure changes.

> SELECT *

is bad practice, IMO, for anything but ad-hoc type queries.

Comment: You're right about Select * being bad practice. I am converting a java project to powershell so I just copied and pasted the query they used. Thank you I will make some adjustments and see what happens.

Comment: Ok NVL worked very well for columns that are always null but it did not work for columns that only have a few null values and coalesce seems to skip records with null values which won't help me.

Comment: Exception calling "GetInt64" with "1" argument(s): "Specified cast is not valid."
At C:\users\klynch\test.ps1:23 char:34
+     $invoice_num=$reader.GetInt64 <<<< (5)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: When you use NVL, what did you convert the null value to?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the current row has a null for a given column with

```
if ($reader.IsDBNUll(column)) {
  # Handle null
} else {
  # Get the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve issue with this is to use: `GetOracleDecimal()` and `GetOracleString()`.
In this case `null` will be shown as a value and you will not have any null errors.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the `reader.GetOracleValue` method, which will return one of the [Oracle Data Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/oratypes.htm) objects. These objects can store null values and so each has an `IsNull` property to check for null and a `Value` property and possibly also conversion methods, e.g. `ToInt32`, to get the value in a normal .NET type.