# powershell oracle query - dynamically assign reader object member

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oracle, powershell

I have to query many oracle database tables using powershell.
Is there a way to dynamically build the variables to use for the reader object members?

I have to specify the reader object member names like GetInt64(3), GetString(4), and so on for me to retrieve values for each column in the table.

Since I have to enumerate so many tables with varying column names, it will be a lot of work to write this out.

How can I write it so I can use the variable names instead of the member names? thnx - this is my very first post here on this web site.

This is the part of the below code that is being referenced in my question.

```
.
.
$premise=$reader.GetInt64(3)
$license=$reader.GetString(4)
$invoice_num=$reader.GetInt64(5)
.
.
.
```

I got this example from this link(I wasn't sure if I was supposed to post a follow up question on the same thread.:
[Handling nulls in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564240/handling-nulls-in-powershell)

```
# Create a datareader for a SQL statement 
$sql="select * from legacydb.ebt_invoice_dtl where premnum = 397743"
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand( $sql,$conn)
$reader=$command.ExecuteReader()

# Write out the result set structure 
for ($i=0;$i -lt $reader.FieldCount;$i++) {
Write-Host  $reader.GetName($i) $reader.GetDataTypeName($i) 
}

# Write out the results 
while ($reader.read()) {
$dtl_id=$reader.GetDecimal(0)  
$invoice_id=$reader.GetDecimal(1)
$debtor=$reader.GetInt64(2)
$premise=$reader.GetInt64(3)
$license=$reader.GetString(4)
$invoice_num=$reader.GetInt64(5)
$deb_cred=$reader.GetString(6)
$inv_ref=$reader.GetString(7)
$rate=$reader.GetDecimal(8)
$charge=$reader.GetDouble(9)
$usage=$reader.GetInt64(10)
$tax=$reader.GetDouble(11)
$rate_code=$reader.GetString(12)
$inv_date=$reader.GetDateTime(13)
$missed=$reader.GetString(14)
$change_date=$reader.GetDateTime(15)
$dnp=$reader.GetString(16)

Write-Host "$dtl_id $invoice_id $debtor $premise $license $invoice_num $deb_cred        $inv_ref $rate $charge $usage $tax $rate_code $inv_date $missed $change_date $dnp "
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, you could use `$reader.item('columnname')` to get the value in the specified column by name.

A more idomatic way to go would be to create objects and then pipe them to Format-Table to do output.

Assuming the column names are your variable names, here's a helper function to read the objects from the reader:

```
function Get-OracleDbObject
{
   param(
       [string]$Query,
       [Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection]$Connection
   )

   $command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand $Query, $Connection
   $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()

   while($reader.Read()) {
        $props = @{}
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i+=1) {
            $name = $reader.GetName($i)
            $value = $reader.item($i)
            $props.Add($name, $value)   
        }
        $obj = new-object PSObject -Property $props
        Write-Output $obj
   }

   $reader.Dispose()
   $command.Dispose()
}
```

Then you could just do this write things into columns:

```
$sql = "select * from legacydb.ebt_invoice_dtl where premnum = 397743"
Get-OracleDbObject -Query $sql -Connection $conn | Format-Table *
```

Comment: Thank you! - these codes are bit advance for me(I will study more on this), but I got the code working using my table structure. I forgot to ask though - how do I also output the column names dynamically? Because I need to get all the columns for many tables that I do not know the column names when I query and again will be a lot of typing. Can I build the variables for this part of the code? "Format-Table dtl_id, invoice_id, debtor, license, invoice_num,...." Sorry I should have asked the question in more explicit manner. thanks again.

Comment: @ikask You can use `Format-Table *` to print out all the properties for an object. In this case, just `Format-Table` (no arguments) might work as well since there's no default way to display these custom objects. I added this to the answer and cleanup a little, hopefully its a little easier to use now.

Comment: thanks mike z. Format-table * did the job. I will try out the revision & get an understanding for both codes.