# Extra space in custom PSObject

Tags: powershell

I'm building custom PSObject arrays yet I'm noticing a lot of extra space being inserting for no apparent reason. Example:

```
PS> $user = @()
PS> $user += New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Name" = "John Smith"}
PS> $user += New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Age" = "18"}
PS> $user += New-Object PSObject -Property @{"City of birth" = "New York"}
PS> $user += New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Pet" = "none"}
PS> "[$($user.Name)]"
[John Smith   ]
PS> "[$($user.Pet)]"
[   none]
```

Seems like the more key/value pairs I add, the more space is added to those values. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: You are building an array... shouldn't you access the user via `"[$($user[0].Name)]"` - first element in the array, selecting the NoteProperty Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mike-z for the comment about `Add-Member`. Turns out that this code does what I wanted:

```
PS> $user = New-Object PSObject
PS> $user | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue "John Smith"
PS> $user | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Age" -NotePropertyValue "18"
PS> $user | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "City of birth" -NotePropertyValue "New York"
PS> $user | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Pet" -NotePropertyValue "none"
```

Answer (score 2):

`$user` is an array so the behavior for `$user.Name` is get the Name property for all entries. Since it is being put into a string the values are joined together by spaces. Thus every time you add an entry to `$user` an additional space is added somewhere to all the properties.

I'm not quite sure you are defining `$user` as an array. It would make more sense to build a hashtable of all the properties and use that initialize `$user` as a PSObject:

```
$props = @{ "Name" = "John Smith"; "Age" = "18"; "City of birth" = "New York"; "Pet" = "none"}
$user = New-Object PSObject -Property $props
```

or if you need to build some properties dynamically:

```
$props = @{ "Name" = "John Smith"; "Age" = "18"; "City of birth" = "New York"; "Pet" = "none"}
if ($myCondition) 
{
    $props.PropertyA = "A"
}
else
{
    $props.PropertyB = "B"
}
$user = New-Object PSObject -Property $props
```

or if you are reading them from a [database it would probably look more like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320707/powershell-oracle-query-dynamically-assign-reader-object-member/26321271#26321271):

```
while($reader.Read()) {
     $props = @{}
     for($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i+=1) {
        $name = $reader.GetName($i)
        $value = $reader.item($i)
        $props.Add($name, $value)   
     }
     $obj = new-object PSObject -Property $props
     Write-Output $obj
}
```

Comment: I know I can add them all at once, but the problem is I'm iterating some data and don't know in advance what all of the properties will be. I can't set them all on one line. If doing an array and op_adding them isn't the right way to build the object, how can I build it over time?

Comment: You can also add a property to an exiting object later using [Add-Member](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx)